# base64 encode an image without saving

Tags: php, base64, gd

Can I base64 encode an image that I created on the fly, without first saving it to disk? As far as I know, `base64_encode()` only accepts strings, and I couldn't find a way to retrive image source object as string without first saving it, and load it with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I would advise against using `file_get_contents()` as it can be very very very slow sometimes. Use curl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GD doesn't provide a method to return an output image as text, but you can fake it with the output buffering functions:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($handle); // no second parameter, will do output instead of writing to file
$img = ob_get_clean();

echo base64_encode($img);
```